# Number of permutations of n numbers with given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a set *S* of *m* unique numbers, *n* slots are to be filled using those *m* numbers. What are the number of ways to do it, given the following constraints:

- A particular number from those *m* numbers should always be present in atleast one of the slots, and that number *x* will be given.
- Any number can be picked any number of times, i.e., repetition is allowed in the slots.
- Two ways are different if atleast one of the slots differ.

Example:
*S* = {2, 4, 6}, So, *m* = 3. Given, *n* = 4 and *x* = 2.
Here, *x* = 2, so in all of the ways, 2 will be present in atleast one of the slots.
Few of the possible ways to fill the given *n* slots are:
[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2, 6]

I have found a pattern to solve this using the number of times *x* is repeated in the slots, like in the given example it can be repeated 1, 2, 3 or 4 times, and for each number of times, we can count the number of possible permutations for other remaining numbers in *S* but this process is too lengthy. Is there any shorter way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ occurs exactly once. Then the number of possibilities is
$$\binom{n}{1}(m-1)^{n-1}$$
If $x$ occurs twice, then the possibilities are
$$\binom{n}{2}(m-1)^{n-2}$$
etc. Thus the total number is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}(m-1)^{n-k}}$$
By the binomial theorem, this is the same as
$$((m-1)+1)^n-\binom{n}{0}(m-1)^n=m^n-(m-1)^{n}$$
It is perhaps easier to see it this way: There are $m^n$ possibilities, and there are $(m-1)^n$ configurations with no slot having $x$. So the answer is
$$m^n-(m-1)^n$$

Comment: Why didn't i see that! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user155768 You're welcome.